# Ruby on Rails style: Model#attr_name? method

Tags: ruby-on-rails

My Person model has a `vip` attribute backed by ActiveRecord, so it's got `vip` and `vip=` methods automatically. This attribute was initially a boolean, but needs to change to an integer to allow for several categories of importance/prestige/etc, and since there are already many references to the boolean value, I thought I'd add a method like:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  def vip?
    self.vip >= 10
  end
end
```

So I could fix existing calls to `#vip` with calls to `#vip?`. Is it bad practice, or just confusing to do it like this, with `#vip` storing the level of importance and `vip?` checking whether a record is "important enough"? The naming is a little tangled because `status` is already taken by another column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `predicate method` should return `true` or `false`, but you can stablish the condition that you want. Regardless of the method name, I think what you have done is right.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  def vip?
    vip >= 10 # self is unnecesary
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you're on the right track with renaming the attribute. `vip?` returns whether the attribute in question exceeds a certain value. Maybe the attribute should be something like `credits`, `points`, or `reputation`? I think of something like StackOverflow itself in this regard. Users have a cumulative `reputation` score. Some badges are assigned based simply on this cumulative score. While this is likely a composite score of all the up votes, questions, answers, etc. a user has received, your data might be a simple integer value from which you can base status. vBulletin and other forum software also have this based on the number of posts and other attributes.

Comment: It's not quite right for my particular use case, but your `reputation` suggestion is a good one!